# Active Select option in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am working on a mobile version of my website. I have the option Action working however when I select, for example "About" it will take me to the correct page but the navigation bar goes back to the "Home" option. How do I go about doing this? thanks in advance

```
<select class="navbar-nav" style="width:250px" onchange='location.href = this.value'>
                <option value="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</option>
                <option value="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">About</option>
                <option value="@Url.Action("Products", "Home")">Products</option>
                <option value="@Url.Action("Services", "Home")">Services</option>
                <option value="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")">Contact</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <option selected="@ViewBag.Home" value="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</option>
    <option selected="@ViewBag.About" value="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">About</option>
    <option selected="@ViewBag.Products" value="@Url.Action("Products", "Home")">Products</option>
    <option selected="@ViewBag.Services" value="@Url.Action("Services", "Home")">Services</option>
    <option selected="@ViewBag.Contact" value="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")">Contact</option>
```

and in your Home.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Home = true;
}
```

and the other pages.

Comment: went with this option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
@{
    Dictionary<string, string> menu = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    menu.Add("Home", @Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
    menu.Add("About", @Url.Action("About", "Home"));
    menu.Add("Products", @Url.Action("Products", "Home"));
    menu.Add("Services", @Url.Action("Services", "Home"));
    menu.Add("Contact", @Url.Action("Contact", "Home"));    

}
<select class="navbar-nav" style="width:250px" onchange='location.href = this.value'>
   @foreach (var m in menu)
   {
     <option value="@m.Value" @(m.Value == Request.Url.AbsoluteUri ? "selected='selected' " : "")>@m.Key</option>  
   } 
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this one, the navigation worked correctly but it was still doing the same thing. thanks though

Comment: try put space on " selected='selected'" instead of. 
or "selected='true'"